# Проблема с выделением ссылки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть проблема. Как видно на скриншоте, есть кнопка, при нажатии которой в дропдаун загружаются через AJAX уведомления, но минус в том, что, когда нажимаешь два раза эту кнопке, то текст выделяется, а такого нет ни на каких сайтах.
Как можно решить проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете ввиду выделение текста мышкой, то можно задать `user-select`:

```css
a{
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Уведомления</a>
```

Comment: я думаю что не совсем то что нужно, если поставить user select:none тогда выделения вообще не будет, а ему нужно чтобы при двойном клике только его не было